# Set priority for regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex: `(.*)(A|B|AB)(.*)`
when my string is aaaABccc 
result of this regex:

`Full match    0-8 aaaABccc
 Group 1.   0-4 aaaA
 Group 2.   4-5 B
 Group 3.   5-8 ccc`

problem: i want matching follow result:

`Full match    0-8 aaaABccc
 Group 1.   0-4 aaa
 Group 2.   4-5 AB
 Group 3.   5-8 ccc`

How i can change my regex to do it? please help me, thank a lot!

Comment: Would you please try: `(.*?)(AB|A|B)(.*)`

Comment: `([a-z]+)(AB?)(.*)` Does this work?

Comment: @TheGridLock Dou you think OP might also want to match "aaaAaaa"? I think so, though admittedly they to not clearly say so.

Comment: Can A or B be in the first part of the word or does the first part consist of characters completely different?

Comment: So i want to match aaaAccc or aaaBccc if present, how i change my regex?

Comment: Hi @VănNguyễnDuy, please see my answer (or any other answer). If none of them meets your requirements, please adjust your question. (My try is: `(.*?)(AB|A|B)(.*)`)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not only related to the priority, but that the first group is greedy. It tries to be as long as possible.
So adjusting to this will work (even with your alternatives):

```
(.*?)(AB|A|B)(.*)
```

`?` transforms a quantifier to a non-greedy version: `.*` (any character, greedy) becomes `.*?` (any character, non-greedy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

`(.*)(AB)(.*)`

Comment: Judging from the fact that OP uses `(A|B|AB)`, they want e.g. "aaaAaaa" to also match, which I think it won't with your proposal. Not 100% clear question on that detail, I admit.

Comment: I want my pattern so match aaaAaaa or aaaBaaa or aaaABaaa, but i prefer aaaABaaa more aaaAaaa, aaaBaaa, how i fix them?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the dataset you are using, mayby you could give us more information about it. but by now it looks like we can use the fact that the prefix and postfix are lowercase chars:

```
\b([a-z]*)(A|B|AB)([a-z]*)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/wQFtt9/2

We could generalise more if you need to. If A or B could not be present in the first or last part the use this. `[^AB\n]` means mathc everythin that is not a A or B or a newline (the part with the newline is necessary if you have a multiline dataset).

```
\b([^AB\n]*)(A|B|AB)([^AB\n]*)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/wQFtt9/3